# How to select unique XML nodes using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML, I am trying to get the unique nodes based on the name child node.

Original XML:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>White Socks</name>
    <price>2.00</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>White Socks/name>
    <price>2.00</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Blue Socks</name>
    <price>3.00</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>White Socks</name>
    <price>2.00</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Blue Socks</name>
    <price>3.00</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

I've tried various things but not worth listing here, the closest I got was using XPath but that just returned the names like below. However, this is wrong as I want the full XML as above, not just the node values.

```
White Socks
Blue Socks
```

I'm using Ruby and trying to iterate over the nodes like so:

```
@doc.xpath("//product").each do |node|
```

Obviously the above currently gets ALL product nodes, whereas I want all unique product nodes (using the child node "name" as the unique identifier)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT 1.0 solution. Extensive explanation is also provided. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kProdByName" match="product"
  use="name"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "product
    [not(generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('kProdByName',name)[1])
         )
    ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (corrected to be well-formed):**

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>White Socks</name>
        <price>2.00</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>White Socks</name>
        <price>2.00</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Blue Socks</name>
        <price>3.00</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>White Socks</name>
    <price>2.00</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Blue Socks</name>
    <price>3.00</price>
  </product>
</products>
```

**Do note**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every node "as-is".
2. The **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** is used.
3. There is a single overriding template that excludes any `product` element that is not the first in its group.

---

**XPath-one-liner** (Note this is O(N^2) -- will be *very* slow on many `product` elements):

```
 /*/product[not(name = following-sibling::product/name)]
```

Comment: Can this be done using Xpath alone? So I can combine into my Ruby statement??

@doc.xpath("//product").each do |node|

Comment: Something like this.. But not this, if you know what I mean :)? 

 @doc.xpath("//product[not(.=following::name)]").each do |node|

Comment: @zinc: Yes, and I have updated my answer with this one-liner XPath solution. Be warned, though, that it is very inefficient compared to the Muenchian method.

Comment: slow is ok, as this is being used for importing into a DB

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT you can use Muenchian grouping to eliminate duplicates as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="prod-by-name" match="product" use="name"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('prod-by-name', name)[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```